# C++ 2010, corruption of the heap?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
void IRC_MESSAGE::GetHeader()
{
    int find_first = this->FindChar(this->MessageText, ':');
    int find_second = 0;
    if(find_first > -1) {
        find_second = this->FindChar(this->MessageText+(find_first + 1), ':');
        if(find_second > -1) {
            //dies here on this message
            //this->MessageText = ":irc.betawarz.com 001 Fatal-Error[B] :Welcome to the Beta IRC Network Fatal-Error[B]!dragon@blank-value.cpe.net.cable.rogers.com"
            this->Header = (char *)malloc((find_second - find_first) + 1);
            ZeroMemory(this->Header, (find_second - find_first) + 1);
            memcpy(this->Header, this->MessageText + (find_first + 1), 
                  (find_second - (find_first + 1)));
            return;
        } else {
            this->Header = (char *)malloc(find_first + 1);
            ZeroMemory(this->Header, find_first + 1);
            if(find_first == 0) {
                this->Header = "";
            } else {
                memcpy(this->Header, this->MessageText, find_first);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    this->Header = "NA";
    return;
}
-----------------------------
char *Header;    char *MessageText;
```

int FindChar(char *, char), just returns the first index of said value, and returns -1 if none are found.

My problem here is where i have it marked that it dies here, when it has the following MessageText.
It crashes saying: This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in ApplicationX.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
Yet I get 3 or 4 messages prior to this that don't toss this crash.
Can anyone else here see my problem in this.

Comment: Use `new` and `delete` in C++, not `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: You do not need all the `this->` in the code

Comment: Are you are using MFC?

Comment: Show us the `IRC_MESSAGE` class

Comment: Dumped it on Mega File Upload. [link](http://www.megafileupload.com/eoX1/irc_message.rar)
Little to much to copy and paste line by line with the site heh.

Comment: No. Show a [mcve]. You'll need to cut the code down first. Then post here and not in an off site link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is in here

```
        this->Header = (char *)malloc((find_second - find_first) + 1);
        ZeroMemory(this->Header, (find_second - find_first) + 1);
        memcpy(this->Header, this->MessageText + (find_first + 1), 
              (find_second - (find_first + 1)));
```

The `malloc()` allocates `find_second-find_first+1` char characters.   The `memcpy()` call copies `find_second - find_first - 1` characters from `this->MessageText + find_first + 1`.    The minimum value of both `find_first` and `find_second` are both zero, in which case `find_second-find_first - 1` is `-1` as an `int`.

However, the third argument of `memcpy()` is of type `size_t`, which is an `unsigned` type.   The value of `-1` when converted to `size_t` is therefore the maximum value a `size_t` can represent  (say, `4294967295` if `size_t` is a 32-bit type).  It is a fair bet that copying `4294967295` in some circumstances is not what you intend - particularly, given that size allocated by the preceding `malloc()` is `1`.

Another problem is that the statement `this->Header = "";`, causes the previous value of `this->Header` (returned by preceding `malloc()`)to be lost.  At minimum, that is a memory leak.   If some other code calls (in effect) `free(this->Header)`, the result is undefined behaviour, since the string literal `""` is not allocated using `malloc()`.

More generally, consider using the `std::string` type.   It has a number of facilities that would be helpful, and cleanly appends strings when needed - without the prospect of memory management errors like you are demonstrating.

And don't use `this->` unless you really need it.   In your code it just makes things less clear, and is almost certainly not needed.

Comment: what it does is grabs the string value between : and :, if it dosent find the second :, it will go into the else statement and return the string from 0 to where the first : was found if it was 0 anyways it returns the header as "".
there will always be atleast 1.

Comment: @Jaime You are out of your depth here. This isn't how to write C++. Consider revisiting the basics and questioning whether or not you have mastered them.

Comment: after converting that over to entirely std::string, i found my problem not within this class but in another location. just converted over from char * to char[]. seems weird still, but working again. I'll give you a + regardless of the last message.

Comment: @Jaime.    Changing over to `std::string` would have - assuming you did it in a sound way - eliminated at least one problem I described here.  That's why I suggested it.    It probably then gave an opportunity for some other problem in your code to become obvious.    Converting from `char *` to `char []` would not have fixed the problem but, depending on where you did it and how the compiler works, may have changed the symptoms.   And I didn't write the "last message".

Comment: my bad lmao, i might just go over the entire program still im not blowing through it only reason i came across this was i jumped out of debug mode and decided to release one, i have a bad habit of just being on debug.